# TYPO3 9.2.1 Create ViewHelper in Composer Mode

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, view-helpers, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to create a ViewHelper with a TYPO3 which was installed in composer mode and a site package which was generated with the [sitepackagebuilder](https://sitepackagebuilder.com).

The autoloading should be configured correctly, nevertheless the only thing I'm getting is an error message, that the ViewHelper cannot be found:

```
#1407060572: Fluid parse error in template Standard_action_Default_9cc8c1fca58b49310db5d43052e614cefdb1c728, line 5 at character 6. Error: The ViewHelper "<foobar:some>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "Foo\Bar\ViewHelpers\SomeViewHelper", however this class does not exist. (error code 1407060572). Template source chunk: <foobar:some /> (More information)

TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Parser\Exception thrown in file
/var/www/html/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/TemplateParser.php in line 157.
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. install TYPO3 in composer mode (newest version 9.2.1)
2. create a site package with https://sitepackagebuilder.com - simple configuration, 'foo' as company name and 'bar' as extension key (see screenshot below)
3. create a simple class `SomeViewHelper` under `Classes/ViewHelpers/`
4. modify the template under `Page/Default` to contain the `SomeViewHelper` (following the example from [docs.typo3.org](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html))

   `{namespace foobar=Foo\Bar\ViewHelpers}
   <foobar:some />`
5. create a new root page in TYPO3 with simple content and include the `bar` extension (Template > Includes)

The autoloading of the code should be handled by the `composer.json`/`ext_emconf.php` files which are generated by the sitepackagebuilder.

#### Screenshot

[image: site package builder configuration]

### Code

#### SomeViewHelper.php

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\ViewHelpers;


use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

class SomeViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    public function render() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

#### Page/Default.html

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">

    {namespace foobar=Foo\Bar\ViewHelpers}
    <foobar:some />

    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}" />

</f:section>
```

also declaring the namespace at the top of the document did not help

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:foobar="http://typo3.org/ns/Foo/Bar/ViewHelpers">
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">

    <foobar:some />

    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}" />

</f:section>
</html>
```

#### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "foo/bar",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "https://www.foo.com",
    "license": ["GPL-2.0-or-later"],
    "keywords": ["TYPO3 CMS"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^8.7 || ^9.0",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^8.7 || ^9.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^8.7 || ^9.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\Bar\\": "Classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

#### ext_emconf.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Extension Manager/Repository config file for ext "bar".
 */
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = [
    'title' => 'Bar',
    'description' => '',
    'category' => 'templates',
    'constraints' => [
        'depends' => [
            'typo3' => '8.7.0-9.5.99',
            'fluid_styled_content' => '8.7.0-9.5.99',
            'rte_ckeditor' => '8.7.0-9.5.99'
        ],
        'conflicts' => [
        ],
    ],
    'autoload' => [
        'psr-4' => [
            'Foo\\Bar\\' => 'Classes'
        ],
    ],
    'state' => 'stable',
    'uploadfolder' => 0,
    'createDirs' => '',
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => 1,
    'author' => 'John Doe',
    'author_email' => 'jd@foo.com',
    'author_company' => 'foo',
    'version' => '1.0.0',
];
```

Comment: I would remove the screenshot. You have all the necessary information in composer.json etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that you started with the sitepackagegenerator provided by Benjamin Kott and installed Typo3 in composer mode the following happens:**

---

The sitepackage's TypoScript part is configured via the Typo3 backend so the loading of the TypoScript as well as templates is independent of the php autoloading.

The autoload configuration specified under `public/typo3conf/ext/<extension>` in `composer.json` and `ext_emconf.php` is ignored by `composer` because `composer` does **not** know about these extensions, but composer will still show your extension in the list of extensions:

```
The following extensions have been added to the generated PackageStates.php file: core, extbase, fluid, frontend, fluid_styled_content, install, setup, rte_ckeditor, about, adminpanel, backend, belog, beuser, documentation, extensionmanager, felogin, filelist, form, impexp, info, recordlist, redirects, reports, saltedpasswords, scheduler, sys_note, t3editor, tstemplate, viewpage, <extension>
```

Even if the autoloading is configured correctly composer cannot show any informatiom about your extension:

```
composer info foo/bar

  [InvalidArgumentException]  
  Package foo/bar not found
```

So while this is confusing all you have to do is [include individual extensions like sitepackages](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/latest/MigrateToComposer/MigrationSteps.html#include-individual-extensions-like-sitepackages) (add the following to the end of your **root** `composer.json` - where you also specified things like `"require": { "typo3/minimal": "^9.3" }`):

```
,
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Foo\\Bar\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/<extension>/Classes/"
  }
}
```

---

After that the example posted in the question should work as expected and the result of `<foobar:some />` should be `Hello World`.

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:foobar="http://typo3.org/ns/Foo/Bar/ViewHelpers">
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">

    <foobar:some />

    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}" />

</f:section>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are recognized by the autoloader. If you create a new class you've to refresh the autoloading information by deleting the autoload information.
This information can be deleted with the installtool or manually by removing all files in the folder typo3conf/autoload.
Autoload information for TYPO3 will be created new then.

**Edit:**
Depending on the version the autoload-directory might be in typo3temp which seems being the case here. Sorry for confusion.

It's probably advisable and perhaps even required to include the viewHelper in the template- or layout-file in the top of the file. That's at least what I saw in all fluid-templates I opened.
I never saw yet that a viewhelper is included inside the template.

Comment: I don't have a autoload folder under typo3conf.

Comment: Also I tried to run `composer dumpautoload` which also did a `typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure` and `typo3cms install:generatepackagestates` but the result is still the same.

Comment: Files are in typo3temp/autoload/

Comment: I deleted the typo3temp/autoload dir once (not only the content) and it wasn't created afterwards - now I created the folder myself but the result is still the same (with and without the empty autoload dir).

Is there any command for the installtool to dump/recreate the autoload files for my extension?

Comment: Are you sure the Namespace in the file is  correct?

Comment: If the autoload-files are not re-created there  might be still another problem.
Perhaps a php-fault in the viewHelper-class.

Comment: I basically copied the content from the custom ViewHelper example from typo3.org and modified it to match my package/namespace - so I don't think that there should be a problem (see code above). Regarding the namespace: I checked them repeatedly (see code above), they definitely match and I don't know what could possibly be wrong or how to debug what's wrong with the autoloading.

Comment: I also provided some code for the namespace declared in the top of the document regarding your edit but I still get the same error message and the autoload dir is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is installed with Composer as stated in the question.

There are basically 2 ways to make an extension available via Composer (there are more but we simplify here):

1. Installed it with Composer from a remote source (such as Packagist), e.g. like `composer require myvendor/myextension`? This way the autoloading should work. You can also do `composer dump-autoload` at any point.
2. Do not require the extension but configure the autoloading directly.

I assume you want the latter for your sitepackage. You do not wish to install your sitepackage via Composer from a source such as Packagist on your development machine, because you are currently developing it.

For the autoloading to work, you can add the following to your composer.json file (replace myvendor, myextension):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Myvendor\\Myextension\\": "typo3/sysext/myextension/Classes/",
        ...
    }
}
```

Do not do this for all your extensions, just the ones you do not want to install via Composer!

After you added the autoload configuration, you should run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

See

- This is also explained in the ["Migrate TYPO3 Project to Composer"](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/MigrateToComposer/MigrationSteps.html#include-individual-extensions-like-site-packages) chapter in the official documentation
- [composer.json file of TYPO3 CMS core](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/composer.json)

Answer (score 0):

My answer concerns TYPO3 9.5.+ (composer mode): Extensions that are not installed via composer (like a sitepackage) are not recognised. Therefore a local repo should be created and added to composer-json. Here is what I did:

1. In the root directory I created a folder "packages"
2. I moved my sitepackage extension into that folder ("packages/my-sitepackage")
3. In the root-composer.json (the one which setup TYPO3), I added a "path" repository to my existing ones:

   "repositories": [
   {
   "type": "composer",
   "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
   },
   {
   "type": "vcs",
   "url": "[some path to github or bitbucket]"
   },
   {
   "type": "path",
   "url": "packages/my-sitepackage",
   "options": {
   "symlink": true
   }
   }
   ],
   [...]

(Instead of "packages/my-sitepackage" it should also be possible to use "packages/*"; and symlink could be set to false, too.)

4. Eventually, the extension is required like this:

   "require": {
   "my-sitepackage": "@dev"
   }

The composer docu lists examples using "*", but in my case i had to use "@dev" to make it work.

Some links that helped me:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

Hope that helps those, who come a little later to the game then the question was asked. :-)